# Dataset won't upload with datastore

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-portal

I have an SQL Server database that I have connected to Portal using a datastore. There are three datasets inside this database but for some reason only one of the three datasets are actually uploading into the datastore. How do I get the other two to connect as well?

Comment: It is hard to know exactly without knowing more about the tables.  If they were created outside the ESRI ecosystem or create manually, then ArcGIS will not know to show them and you may need to register the tables with Enterprise's own meta-tables. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/register-a-table-or-view-with-the-geodatabase.htm

Comment: ArcGIS won't do cross-database operations; each database needs its own entry as a Data Store.

Comment: its only one database, but we've already solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue ended up being that ArcGISService hadn't been given editing rights to the datasets within the database. Once that was corrected it uploaded fine